# Create a matrix out of remaining data from a random row selection of a matrix, and use data to calculate RMSE in R

Tags: r, random, matrix, statistics

I have a matrix[A] with 42 rows and 2 columns.  I then have a function that selects randomly 12 of these rows, does a linear regression of the randomly selected matrix and outputs the coefficients (slope and intercept) of the linear regression.

In R, I want to then get the other 30 rows from the original matrix that were not selected in my random function, and then use that data with my newly calculated coefficients, to generate a point (y-value).  So I will have 30 y-values, and then from there I would like to calculate the RMSE (http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/f/b/efb7882a7dbfa5fe48d771565d2675f3.png) using the new y-values, and 1 of the columns in my new 30 row matrix.

The code below is what I currently have right now:

```
#Calibration Equation 1 (TC OFF)
```

A <- matrix(c(Box.CR, Box.DC.ww), nrow=42)

randco <- function(A) {

```
B<- A[sample(42,12),]
lm(B[,2] ~ B[,1])$coefficients
```

}

Z <- t(replicate(10000, randco(A)))

Comment: Notice that if you have duplicate rows in A, you will need a method to handle duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arows <- apply(A, 1, paste, collapse="_")
brows <- apply(B, 1, paste, collapse="_")
A[-match(brows, arows), ]
```

---

---

#### Alternative method, converting matrix to data.table

(not recommended, if your sole purpose is whats described above)

```
library(data.table)
A <- as.data.table(A)

B <- A[sample(nrow(A), 12)]

setkey(A)
setkey(B)
A[!B]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This does exactly what I wanted with regards to selecting the other rows in the matrix. Would you be able to help with the second part of my question, where I need to now use this new matrix to then calculate some new values using the previously calculated coefficients? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jason, in this forum, generally when there are two questions, you should post them as two separate questions as this serves as a reference for others who might search for these in the future